# Difference between ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, software-recommendations

Does ArcGIS Desktop have any special features compare to ArcGIS online apart from workflow feature ?

What are the differences between ArcGIS Desktop and ArcGIS Online with details?

In ArcGis Our data will be shared to ArcGIS team, how we can secure the data from ArcGIS team?

Which license will be enough to create a small layer and use in our desktop and online version?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the following links:

- [What is ArcGIS Online?](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/what-is-agol.htm)
- [ArcGIS Online Frequently asked questions](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/faq.htm)
- [What is ArcMap?](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/main/what-is-arcmap-.htm)

They are very different products, used for different purposes.  If trying to decide which or whether to buy, I recommend you contact [Esri Sales (or your local reseller)](http://www.esri.com/about-esri/contact) to discuss which may be the best license for your and your organisation.

Comment: i want to know details about ARC GIS Desktop ? . I have not found any differences in the above links.

Comment: @user1494156 The first two links tell you about ArcGIS Online.  The third link tells you about ArcMap (the main Map software in the ArcGIS Desktop suite).  As I said they are very different products, so best to do some research about what they do (those links are a good start point) and you can draw some conclusions about the differences.  Bus as I recommend, to help you determine which license is best you should discuss with Esri sales.